# Axios post returning 405 - Method Not Allowed (Dot Net Core 6, Razor Page & Axios)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, axios, http-status-code-405

I am facing issue with Axios, if I post simple form data it is all working fine. But if I add file input and configures Axios to post files as well, then Server returns error in response "405 - Method not allowed".

Axios configuration which works with simple data:

```
const httpClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: document.location.origin,
    headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XHR'}
});
```

Axios configuration which is NOT working in case of post files

```
const httpClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: document.location.origin,
    headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XHR', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
});
```

Razor Page Post Method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    //await Mediator.Send(Command);

   
    return RedirectToPageJsonResult("./");
}
```

Cshtml snippet:

```
<form method="post" data-os-trigger="xhr" class="form-horizontal form-groups-bordered" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Command.Status"/>
                    <input type="file" asp-for="@Model.Command.FileField" />
                    
                    <div class="row button">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                           
                            <button id="btnSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Save</button>
                            <button type="reset"  class="btn btn-light">Clear</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</form>
```

JS event which post data:

```
let formData = new FormData($this[0]);
       
        let formParams = new URLSearchParams(formData);
        
        httpClient.post($this[0].action, formParams)
            .then(function (response) {
                                 
               
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
               
            });
```

Comment: Hi, The 405 Method Not Allowed error occurs when the web server is configured in a way that does not allow you to perform a specific action for a particular URL. Pls check what is your `$this[0].action`, if it matches your wanted url.

Comment: Hi @Ovais Khatri, if any update, pls follow up to let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with my code. If you see in my code there are two lines to get params of Form:

```
let formData = new FormData($this[0]); 
let formParams = new URLSearchParams(formData);
```

I was passing formParams as argument in AXIOS call, which was causing the issue. Instead I had to use formData parameter. Once I did that, it was all working fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple working demo you could follow:

Model

```
public class Command
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public IFormFile FileField { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@page 
@model IndexModel

<form asp-page="Index" method="post" data-os-trigger="xhr" class="form-horizontal form-groups-bordered" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Command.Status"/>
        <input type="file" asp-for="@Model.Command.FileField" />                    
        <button id="btnSave" type="button" onclick="PostFile()" class="btn btn-warning">Save</button>
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function PostFile()
        {
            const httpClient = axios.create({
            baseURL: document.location.origin,
            headers: { 
                'X-Requested-With': 'XHR', 
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            }
        });
        let formData = new FormData();     
        formData.append("FileField", $("#Command_FileField")[0].files[0]);
        formData.append("Status", $("#Command_Status").val());
        
        httpClient.post($('form').attr('action'), formData)
            .then(function (response) {
                                 
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
               
            });
        }        
    </script>
}
```

PageModel

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Command Command { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        //do your stuff...
    }
}
```